# How do I pause/resume when using ANTLR visitors?

Tags: antlr

I'm using ANTLR visitors to parse a custom scripting language. I would like to be able to pause and resume script execution. The pausing will be triggered externally (i.e. user presses pause button in UI). When execution is resumed, sometimes I want it to pick up right where it left off, while other times I'll need it to backtrack a little. Is this possible in ANTLR? If so, how might I approach this?

I was not able to find any useful information on pausing/resuming in ANTLR.

Comment: That depends on what your target platform (C++/Java for example) provides. For C#/.NET you can simply use locking mechanism like `ManualResetEvent` in your visitor classes. I don't think it is something specific to ANTLR.

Comment: Do you want to modify the source script while paused? The usual approach is to do the processing in multiple steps - first parse the source (using ANTLR) and create a model representing the script, then go through it and execute it (this step is not specific to ANTLR anymore). The pausing then would be done in the part unrelated to ANTLR, and as already mentioned, language-dependent.

Comment: This is not an ANTLR related task. The parser does just that: parsing input. The visitor and listener classes are just help tools to walk over the parse tree (or listen to events related to parsing). A debugger implementation should be totally separate and just use the parse tree as source for the state machine. This debugger can then easily do all the required operations (run, break on break points, step (in/out) etc.).